# How does c# compiler treat this DateTime.ToOADate()?

Tags: c#, datetime, compiler-construction

I need to have very high-performance loop going over large datasets. I need to compare TimeStamps, but my dates are in OA format:

```
if (md.DT_OA > new DateTime(2011, 3, 13).ToOADate())
```

Will the compiler evaluate `new DateTime(2011, 3, 13).ToOADate()` in each loop cycle? Or will the "optimiser" work this out once at beginning.

i.e Can I get away with being lazy and having this in the code?

As you can tell - I don't know much about how compiler works...

EDIT 1

Comments inspired me do do a proper test:

Option 2 below is about `3% faster` than Option 1. Which is surprising not MUCH faster - the compiler seems to be very smart or date creation is fast.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Go();
        }

        public static void Go() 
        {
            int c = 0;
            DateTime st = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 3, 13);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) 
            {
                if (DateTime.Now > new DateTime(2011, 3, 13)) // Option 1
                //if (DateTime.Now > dt)                          // Option 2
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Time taken: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(st).TotalMilliseconds + " c: " + c);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you believe something is a performance bottleneck you should profile and measure. That way you'll *know* which is better. I generally believe that if you don't care enough to measure something, you shouldn't care enough to optimise it. (Though totally fair enough if you're just asking for curiosity's sake)

Comment: @Iain - yes fair enough - I will measure. I was just trying to understand the mechanics a bit.

Comment: re the edit; "date creation is fast." - yes; `DateTime` is a `struct`, so there is no allocation required; and the math (which complicated a bit by months) isn't too horrible, and is pretty optimized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no reason it would optimize that... pretty sure it won't (I *know* it won't optimize it at the IL layer, but that doesn't say anything about the JIT; but I *really* don't think it will - ***it doesn't know that the method is always going to return the same thing each time***).

Instead, lift it out of the loop if you care about it:

```
var oaDate = new DateTime(2011, 3, 13).ToOADate();
...loop...
    if (md.DT_OA > oaDate) {...}
```

---

Re just `new DateTime(int,int,int)` (comments); let's create a test program:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now > new DateTime(2011, 3, 13)) Console.WriteLine("abc");
        }
    }
```

if we compile that and then disassemble the IL (reflector/ildasm/etc), we get:

```
L_0000: ldc.i4.0 
L_0001: stloc.0 
L_0002: br.s L_002b
L_0004: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
L_0009: ldc.i4 0x7db
L_000e: ldc.i4.3 
L_000f: ldc.i4.s 13
L_0011: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.DateTime::.ctor(int32, int32, int32)
L_0016: call bool [mscorlib]System.DateTime::op_GreaterThan(valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime, valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime)
L_001b: brfalse.s L_0027
L_001d: ldstr "abc"
L_0022: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
L_0027: ldloc.0 
L_0028: ldc.i4.1 
L_0029: add 
L_002a: stloc.0 
L_002b: ldloc.0 
L_002c: ldc.i4 0x3e8
L_0031: blt.s L_0004
L_0033: ret
```

Look at L_0009 thru L_0011 - that is creating the `new DateTime` *per loop iteration* (`L_0031: blt.s L_0004` is the loop repeat). The compiler has been very literal with your request, as I would expect.

Comment: Yes I can do that but I have about 20 of these dates, and was trying to be lazy. I believe that the compiler is smart about new DateTime(2011, 3, 13) as I use that elsewhere - it's the .ToOADate() addition that I was wondering about.

Comment: @ManInMoon, you have a “very high-performance loop” and you are trying to be lazy? That doesn't sound like a good combination.

Comment: @ManInMoon no, it isn't smart about that; but the math is simple and not hugely expensive. I'll add an example...

Comment: @svick agreed; when I have a high-perf block I can end up going to crazy extremes, all the way to full meta-programming via IL emit; "good perf" is fine with lazy; "insanely high perf" needs work /cc @ManInMoon,